# Merge React web and React-Native projects into one?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

we are currently developing a project with a Node.js backend, web/mobile web and mobile app front-ends. Currently, the project is split into 2 folders,

- main project (react project)

  - /dist (for distribution)
  - /dev (for development)
  - /src (for source code)

    - /api (backend)
    - /web (web / mobile web front-end)
- app project (react-native project)

  - /android
  - /ios
  - /app (custom code)
  - index.ios.js
  - index.android.js

Since the common folders in both projects are .git, node_modules, and .vscode, I don't see any apparent conflicts. Right now, there's not much common code between the two projects and we can leave each be, but I'm wondering if merging the 2 into a single folder could be more productive. Anyone has any suggestions or opinions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having common stuff in a separate folder / npm project and install it via npm (local or git remote if you don't want to publish it). That way both platforms remain separated (you expect other behaviour from a web app than an ios app), but you may easily interchange code.